# Convert DateTime with NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running this query

```
select * from dbo.CHARGES  m
LEFT JOIN Docs z ON z.DocId=m.DocId
AND CHARGE_DATE=CAST(z.DocDate + z.DocTime AS DATETIME)
```

And getting `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`, since some rows of `DocDate, DocTime` have null value

Here `DocTime` is Varchar(5)

***How can i run this query by ignoring NULL or wrong values?***

Comment: "since some rows of DocDate, DocTime have null value" Nope, thats not it. It is because the data you have in the columns creates a string that does not convert nicely to a datetime.

Comment: What format is `DocDate` date in? You may need to use SQL-Server's [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) rather than `CAST` so you can specify a style, and convert each part individually. e.g. `CONVERT(DATETIME, z.DocDate, 103) + CONVERT(TIME, z.DocTime)`

Comment: A better question though would be, why are you storing time as `VARCHAR(5)`? Why not use the `TIME` datatype?, or if you are storing the DATE and TIME why not just store a single DATETIME column? [Storing dates and times as strings is an abhorrent practice](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and if it is not too late consider redesigning your table!

Comment: @GarethD, The `DocDate` value is like `2006-10-25 00:00:00.000` and the system is in production and designed 3 years back. Now we could not change the design

Comment: @RemusRusanu, The question is how can i run this query by ignoring NULL or wrong values

Comment: to ignore null values, have you checked the possibility to use  `NVL(value, 'replace_value')` function? See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: @zencv, I use SQL Server

Comment: @zencv That doesn't seem very helpful for a question tagged with SQL-Server...

Comment: sorry, i overlooked the second tag

Answer (score 6):

If your strings are in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` then your convert expression will be something like:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(DocDate, '1900-01-01') + ' ' + ISNULL(DocTime, '00:00'), 121)
```

However, it is probably adivisable to check that it actually is a date before you try to convert it:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;

SELECT  DocDate,
        DocTime,
        Formatted = CASE WHEN ISDATE(ISNULL(DocDate, '1900-01-01') 
                                + ' ' + ISNULL(DocTime, '00:00')) = 1

                            THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(DocDate, '1900-01-01') 
                                + ' ' + ISNULL(DocTime, '00:00'), 121)
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
FROM    (VALUES
            ('2013-10-01', '17:30'),-- CORRECT FORMAT
            ('2013-10-01', NULL),   -- NULL TIME
            ('2013-13-10', '17:30'), -- INVALID DATE
            ('2013-01-05', 'XX:30'), -- INVALID TIME
            (NULL, '17:00')         -- NULL DATE
        ) t (DocDate, DocTime);
```

Note, I have set the dateformat even though it is set within the convert, this is for the benefit of `ISDATE()`, if the date format is not set this way, it may think that `2013-13-10` is a valid date (13th October 2013), but will through an error when it comes to the convert.

If/When you upgrade to SQL-Server 2012 you can simply use [TRY_CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SELECT  DocDate,
        DocTime,
        Formatted = TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(DocDate, '1900-01-01') 
                                + ' ' + ISNULL(DocTime, '00:00'), 121)
FROM    (VALUES
            ('2013-10-01', '17:30'),-- CORRECT FORMAT
            ('2013-10-01', NULL),   -- NULL TIME
            ('2013-13-10', '17:30'), -- INVALID DATE
            ('2013-01-05', 'XX:30'), -- INVALID TIME
            (NULL, '17:00')         -- NULL DATE
        ) t (DocDate, DocTime);
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/9967)**

I don't condone this approach, and (as I have in a comment) would strongly advise correcting the problem (which is storing data as the wrong type) rather than jumping through hoops to work around data errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, the query depend of your necessity.

With Null Values

```
select * from dbo.CHARGES  m
LEFT JOIN Docs z 
    ON z.DocId=m.DocId
    AND (
        z.DocDate IS NULL
        OR z.DocTime IS NULL
        OR CHARGE_DATE=CAST(z.DocDate + z.DocTime AS DATETIME)
    )
```

Without Null Values

```
select * from dbo.CHARGES  m
LEFT JOIN Docs z 
    ON z.DocId=m.DocId
    AND (
        NOT z.DocDate IS NULL
        AND NOT z.DocTime IS NULL
        AND CHARGE_DATE=CAST(z.DocDate + z.DocTime AS DATETIME)
    )
```

Comment: I really don't understand this answer.

Comment: In this solution, the filter of date is just used when both field is not null.